# How to use Pythonnet in C# app deployment? It still requires python to be locally installed on any user machine

Tags: python, c#, python-3.x, python.net

**Background**

I was looking for something like IronPython for my C# app, but supporting numpy packages. I decided to give a try to Pythonnet. Everything works fine as long as I'm on my machine with Python installed. But when I deploy my app, and try to start it on another machine, it crashes. My idea is that, Pythonnet is not deployed inside generated exe. This mean that it is usless for me.

**Here an MWE:**

```
var input1 = new double[,] { { 15 }, { 274.5 } };
Runtime.PythonDLL = @"C:\pythonx86.3.11.2\tools\python311.dll";
PythonEngine.Initialize();
dynamic os = Py.Import("os");
dynamic sys = Py.Import("sys");
sys.path.append(os.getcwd());
dynamic test = Py.Import("Test");
int r1 = test.Test_fun(input1);
PythonEngine.Shutdown();
```

**And Test.py**

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.matlib

def Test_fun(x1):

  Q = np.size(x1,1) # samples
  
return Q
```

**Question:**

Is there any way to makes the deployed .exe work on machine without python installed?

Comment: Would something like https://www.py2exe.org be an alternative?

Comment: I'm sorry but not. I have WPF C# application, and python is only a part of the solution. py2exe is dedicated for pure python projects.

Comment: No worries. Was just tossing it out as a thought

Answer (score 2):

You can bundle Python with your app. Just copy it over, no installation required.

Comment: I can, but it is like extra 150 mb. Is there any way to include "lite" version with only core and numpy?